# How to attach css to bean preprocess?

Tags: 7, blocks

So we define the function with this hook...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_bean().
 */
function MODULE_preprocess_bean(&$variables) {

  // Attach css...

  return $variables;
}
```

What can this be attached to please?

```
$variables['SOMETHING']['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/MODULE.css';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be attached to whatever you like - the important thing is that you render it.

So you could quite simply use:

```
$foo['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/MODULE.css';
drupal_render($foo);
```

Or stick it in a var like you're already doing:

```
$variables['SOMETHING']['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/MODULE.css';
```

And in the template:

```
drupal_render($SOMETHING);
```

It works because `drupal_render()` unconditionally calls `drupal_process_attached()` on any element it finds with an `#attached` property, regardless of what you're doing with the result of the render (or if there's even anything *to* render).

Comment: Sorry only just got back, great explanation @Clive, thanks for this, especially about drupal_render() where it calls drupal_process_attached(), didnt know this!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach CSS files using the dedicated function `drupal_add_css` :

```
 drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/MODULE.css');
```

By the way, you don't have to return your `$variables` since it's passed by reference.

I hope that help :)

Comment: The `#attached` method has been preferred for quite a while - this will work, but isn't so good for caching, and won't future-proof the code for Drupal 8